# How do you quickly find the implementation(s) of an interface in Golang?

Tags: go

Let's say I want to find all implementations of the io.ReadCloser interface.

How can I do this in Go?

Comment: The other question is practically asking for the same thing but in terms of SEO: "implementations intereface golang" is way better found than the other question. I didn't find the older question and seeing this question and its answer uprated 9 times within less than 24h it seems that others also don't find it.

Comment: It's not the askers job to worry about search engines. In particular, the language is "Go", not "Golang", it's up to SO's tag to add whatever keywords, etc to help search engines out. (And unless it's relevant/helpful to the title readability, like an "… in/with Go" here, [tags shouldn't be forced into titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/150469)).

Comment: IMO if you are concerned about (or had difficulty) finding the duplicate you could submit an edit to make that question better rather than duplicating it. SO is all about improving questions and answers, not duplicating effort or saying the same thing several different ways, in several different questions, for some search engine. (Note I'm not complaining about you *creating* a duplicate, since you say you looked and couldn't find it; just your response when pointed out that there is a duplicate. This post would be improved by being closed with a link to the existing answers).

Comment: Okay. I have now marked the question as duplicate.

Comment: I also found this one and not the duplicate. And this question has the correct answer 'accepted'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

2015: You can use:

- the [go oracle implements](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SLk36YRjjMgKqe490mSRzOPYEDe0Y_WQNRv-EiFYUyw/view#heading=h.15us5y9rxrbh) command (more recently, 2022, [`go guru`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru), as [seen here](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/20ff7427d3df5cc02d5a619ca0cd9695))
- the [`go types Implements()` function](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/types#Implements) (which was [used by Sourcegraph at one time](https://sourcegraph.com/blog/go-interfaces-and-implementations))

You also have:

- [`dominikh/implements`](https://github.com/dominikh/implements) (uses `go types` as well)
- [`fzipp/pythia`](https://github.com/fzipp/pythia), a browser based user interface (uses `go oracle`)

Comment: go oracle is superseded by go guru

Comment: @hoffmanc Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly. Let me know if I picked the "wrong" guru.